# Dual boot Windows 8 on already installed Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I had three drives on my computer:
C:
D:
E:

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the E: partition and now I'm using Grub boot manager to boot into Windows 7 and Ubuntu

I'm planning to install Windows 8 by removing Windows 7 on C:, but I don't want my old Ubuntu Installation to suffer.

Is there are way that after Windows 8 removes Grub from C: that I'm able to boot to Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

explain to me!
you want dual booting with 
windows 8 mbr or grub mbr!
if it's windows mbr try this :

http://www.iceflatline.com/2009/09/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-linux-using-bcdedit/

I try it by myself!
it's realy work good!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Dual/multi boot Linux/Unix based operating systems using Windows 7/8 boot manager](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html)
explains how to add a boot menu entry for most widely known Linux and Unix descendants like Ubuntu, Fedora, BSD and OSX.

Answer (score -1):

The last time lost Grub I used an Ubuntu live CD to reinstall grub ... worded pretty well. Just make sure you have a working Ubuntu live CD ready before you start to install Windows. I followed more or less the instructions here [How to repair,retore or reinstall grub ...](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/#.UVm82FGaCO0)

It boils down to boot from live CD, mount ubuntu partition from HD, chroot and reinstall grub.